# Why is redux state not mapped to react state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am very very new to React-Redux and encountered a method called **mapstatetoprops**.

However why is redux state not mapped to react state ? Why is it mapped to props instead ?

Comment: React state you mean component state?

Comment: The way I see it, State is for components to manage _internal_ details, and each component sets its own state. Props are for receiving external data (from parent, global state, browser sensors, etc)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  React component state is internal to that component, and outside code cannot modify it.  Props are React's approach for letting outside code (ie, a parent component) pass values into a component.

Answer (score 3):

In React, state belongs to the component while props are passed to the component from it's parent. `mapStateToProps()` is a function that is used inside `connect()` to pass data from the Redux store to a component.

The difference between state and props: https://codeburst.io/react-state-vs-props-explained-51beebd73b21

If you want to use data from the Redux store in a component's state, the component would first need to receive it as a prop. You would then be able to map it to the component's state in `getDerivedStateFromProps`. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

When you derive state from props this way, updating the component's state does not change the Redux state.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason (as I see it):

"Dumb" components deal only with properties, not state.

One motivation for "dumb" components is that they're trivial to test: all you need to do is pass in props. This means that regardless of where the props *come* from the only thing you're testing is that they do the Right Thing with whatever props they're given.

Mapping the redux store to properties reinforces this notion. Once you introduce component state you then have to play more (some easy) games to test the component, but it's not as straight-forward as a pure component.

Answer (score 1):

Cause this is the Redux workflow.

When without redux you use local state (component state) and passes data through parent to children, this makes data sharing very difficult when you have more components.

ComponentOne have data to be passed to component 4:

`ComponentOne -> ComponentTwo -> ComponentThree -> ComponentFour`

With Redux, you have a store, but can't use is as a object (getters and setters), you map it's contents to the components that needs each property.

Redux scenario:

`store {userName: "user", otherData...}`

Dashboard

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        userName : state.userName
}
```

This way the component will listen to `userName` changes, but only can change data in the store through the **mapDispatchToProps**. This way, the [Single Source of Truth](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.md#single-source-of-truth) React principle is assured.